# How to make a horizontal list start in the center of the page?

Tags: css

just a quick CSS question. Does anyone know how to display a horizontal list at the center of the div tag. The number of elements in the list can change from page to page and I was hoping for them to start in the middle of the page. For example if there was only on list item then it would be in the center but if there was two then the first one would move slightly to the left and the second would be slightly to the right. I know the changes have to be made to the ul and li CSS code. This is what I have so far

```
.ui-yt-tabs {
    position: relative;
    width: 740px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 470px;
    height: 117px;
    width: 735px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ul {
text-align:center;
}

ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Just remember to remove `float: left;` from your LI items

Comment: Yes this worked for me. I had tried something similar earlier but I did not remove all the float: left; from all the li code. Thanks for the answer